# Why my div not going to the right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why span5 not going to the right position? Span5 is go to under Span6.I'm linked to bootstrap

My code:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image/logo.png" class="logo_img" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pos">
          <li><a href="#">Ваш город</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Клиники</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Врачи</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Could i ask why would it? In your snippet, you've provided no indication of your css being applied to it?

Comment: Show us you're stylesheet. Don't be ashamed

Comment: default linked bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`.

```css
.span6, .span5 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/40/" class="logo_img" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pos">
          <li><a href="#">Ваш город</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Клиники</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Врачи</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @Shato-UmarDaltsaev: (S)He normally is :P

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, it's hard to advise you're best option. Although one 'simple' styling would be to add `float:right` to your css like so:

```
.span5{
  float:right;
}
```

The Demo below shows this in action:

```css
.span5{
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image/logo.png" class="logo_img" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pos">
          <li><a href="#">Ваш город</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Клиники</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Врачи</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

you could also use the `display` options, like below (aligning logo next to links):

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image/logo.png" class="logo_img" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pos">
          <li><a href="#">Ваш город</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Клиники</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Врачи</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Диагностика</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```